# Divide vector into groups according difference between two neighbouring numbers

Tags: r, data.table

My dummy input vector looks like this:

```
x <- c(10, 20, 30, 70, 80, 90, 130, 190, 200)
```

**What I want**: Add group factor to each number. Group is assigned according difference between neighbouring numbers.

**Example**:
Difference (absolute) between 10 and 20 is 10, hence they belong to same group.
Difference between 30 and 20 is 10 - they belong to same group.
Difference between 30 and 70 is 40 - they belong to different groups.

Given maximal difference `20` **wanted result** is:

```
x group
10     1
20     1
30     1
70     4
80     4
90     4
130    7
190    8
200    8
```

**My code**:

```
library(data.table)
library(foreach)

x <- c(10, 20, 30, 70, 80, 90, 130, 190, 200)

x <- data.table(x, group = 1)
y <- nrow(x)

maxGap <- 20

g <- 1
groups <- 
foreach(i = 2:y, .combine = rbind) %do% {

    if (x[i, x] - x[i - 1, x] < maxGap) {
        g
    } else {
        g <- i
        g
    }
}

x[2:y]$group <- as.vector(groups)
```

**My question**
Given code works, but is too slow with large data (number of rows > 10mil). Is there simpler and quicker solution (not using loop)?

Comment: Maybe try to use the `diff` function. it might speed up your code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An implementation which uses the `rleid` and `shift` functions of *data.table*:

```
x <- c(10, 20, 30, 70, 80, 90, 130, 190, 200)
DT <- data.table(x)

DT[, grp := rleid(cumsum(x - shift(x,1L,0) > 20))]
```

which gives:

```
> DT
     x grp
1:  10   1
2:  20   1
3:  30   1
4:  70   2
5:  80   2
6:  90   2
7: 130   3
8: 190   4
9: 200   4
```

*Explanation*: With `x - shift(x,1L,0)` you calculate the difference with the previous observation of `x`. By comparing it to `20` (i.e.: the `> 20` part) and wrapping that in `cumsum` and `rleid` a runlength id is created.

In response to @Roland's comments: you can leave the `rleid`-part out if you set the `fill` parameter in `shift` to `-Inf`:

```
DT[, grp := cumsum((x - shift(x, 1L, -Inf)) > 20)]
```

Comment: Why use `rleid`? `DT[, grp := cumsum((x - shift(x, 1L, -Inf)) > 20)]` should do the job.

Comment: @Roland True. I used that to start the group numbering at `1` (which can also be achieved by using `cumsum( ... ) + 1`).

Comment: Due to padding with `-Inf` it doesn't start with 0 but with 1.

Comment: @Roland Missed that & thanx. Corrected now.

Answer (score 4):

```
library(IRanges)
x <- c(10, 20, 30, 70, 80, 90, 130, 190, 200)

# If the distance between two integers is larger than 30, 
# then they would be in two groups. Otherwise, they would 
# be in the same group.
ther <- 15

df.1 <- data.frame(val=x, left=x-15, right=x+15)

df.ir <- IRanges(df.1$left, df.1$right)
df.ir.re <- findOverlaps(df.ir, reduce(df.ir))

df.1$group <- subjectHits(df.ir.re)
df.1
#   val left right group
# 1  10   -5    25     1
# 2  20    5    35     1
# 3  30   15    45     1
# 4  70   55    85     2
# 5  80   65    95     2
# 6  90   75   105     2
# 7 130  115   145     3
# 8 190  175   205     4
# 9 200  185   215     4
```

Comment: Another alternative with "IRanges" seems to be `findOverlaps(IRanges(x, x), maxgap = 20L, select = "first")`

Answer (score 2):

```
test <- c(TRUE, diff(x) > 20) #test the differences
res <- factor(cumsum(test)) #groups
#[1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 4 4
#Levels: 1 2 3 4
levels(res) <- which(test) #fix levels
res
#[1] 1 1 1 4 4 4 7 8 8
#Levels: 1 4 7 8
```